How to calculate the radius from a point such that two cylinders do not overlap
I have two cylinders where the centre of their circular faces meet at some point. Knowing the direction vectors of the cylinders to the point where they meet and their respective radii, how can you calculate the distance that they must be moved away from the meeting point so they no longer overlap.
See the diagram below:

Meeting at $\text{B}$, moving the cylinders back along the max of distances $\text{d}$ and $\text{g}$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Added a diagram

See my diagram
Let $\alpha$ be the angle between the two vectors, you can get that from the dot product of the two vectors.
First find $g$:
Consider the triangle ABP, the angle at P is also $\alpha$ and dist(A, B) = $r_2$.
Hence tan($\alpha$) = $r_2 / x_1$, i.e. $x_1 = r_2 $ / tan($\alpha$).
Similarly, for triangle PMJ, the angle at P is also $\alpha$, and so $x_2 = r_1 /$ sin($\alpha$).
$g = x_1 + x_2 = \frac{r_1 + r_2 \cdot cos(\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)}$
The same approach for $d$ gives
$d = \frac{r_2 + r_1 \cdot cos(\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)}$
And you can just take the maximum of these two values.
For the distance A to J, $j_1$, in your diagram, just use Pythagoras and you get that:
If $R$ is the distance,
$R^2 = \frac{r_1^2 + 2 r_1 \cdot r_2 \cdot cos(\alpha) + r_2^2}{sin^2(\alpha)}$.
The cylinders can be reduced to the 2D example since we just use the plane the two vectors lie in to give the worst overlap.
